# Как написать 3D игру на Python, которая работает из консоли Ubunty/Linux и выводящую картинку из AINCII символов?

Tags: python, разработка-игр, консоль

Недавно я задумался о том, возможно ли написать 3D игру для консоли, например для Ubunty. Учитывая то, что в консолях в основном нельзя сделать HD изображение, то сам вывод-изображение должен выглядеть в формате AINCII.
Например так (качество колеблется от разрешения экрана, тут в конверторе была выбрана ширина в 100 символов):
[image: Картина выхода]

Оригинальная картинка (и нет, я не прошу, чтобы кто-то переделал эту игру, я прошу показать библиотеку для этого и её начальные приндципы):
[image: Оригигальная картинка]

Да, я понимаю, что это мазахизм и садизм над консолью. Но меня трудности не остановят.

Comment: почему бы не создать обычную игру , а не этот мазохизм?!

Comment: Ну... Вам этого не понять.

Comment: @root_of_the_live а pygame поддерживает обычные 3д модели ? плоские спрайты его максимум

Comment: На pygame возможен 3Д. Но зачем?! есть куча нормальных движков